# Formatting a changing number

Tags: javascript

I would like to format an increasing number to make it have 2 digits after the decimal place at all times, but I can't seem to make it happen. I have tried using if statements to add 2 zeroes to the end of it, but this method doesn't work very well. Please may I have some help? Thank you!
My code:

```
if (round2(num)<floor(num)+0.001) {
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML='number
'+round2(num)+'.00';}
```

Another method that I have tried:

```
if (round2(num)<floor(num*10)/10+0.001) {
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML='number
'+round2(num)+'.0';}
```

Comment: _"I have tried using if statements"_ please do not tell us, show us it instead using a [mcve].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var xNumber = 23.58841;
console.log(xNumber.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Don’t use `Number` as a variable name.

Comment: Changed the variable name :) Just thought basic knowledge is enough for the learning purpose. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It worked! I thought I tried it before unsuccessfully before but I guess it was all in the situation.